# How to configure Python Logging with YAML to log in UTC?

Tags: python, logging

I know I can set `logging.Formatter().converter = time.gmtime`. But how can I do this in YAML and `logging.config.dictConfig`?

Here is what I did:

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    converter: ext://time.gmtime
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
loggers:
  my_app:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
```

But it still logs in local time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `logging.config` module *only* supports the keys `format`, `datefmt` and `class`; your `converter` key is entirely ignored.

The `class` key does let you specify a custom formatter, so your best option is to subclass `logging.Formatter()` and have that subclass set the converter:

```
from logging import Formatter
import time

class GMTFormatter(Formatter):
    converter = time.gmtime
```

then refer to that class in your YAML:

```
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    class: ext://your.module.GMTFormatter
```

Comment: It only worked when I changed `class: ext://your.module.GMTFormater` to `(): your.module.GMTFormatter`

Comment: Interesting; I am not familiar with how YAML is processed here; I was referring to the [source code of `logging.handlers`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f543863f4e43/Lib/logging/config.py#l104) instead, which uses `class` as the key.

Comment: @rbehzadan I found the reason why you can not use `class`, cause a prefix (ext://) will be convert to the specific class object rather than a string. therefore, you can use `class: "your.module.GMTFormater" ` make it works.